# How to include a style from a Nuget package inside the .NET Maui App.xaml?

Tags: .net, nuget, maui, app.xaml

I have a nuget package that contains some general styles that are used company wide. And I have a .NET Maui application where I want to use these styles.

The project of the nuget package looks like this:

[image]

MyStyle.xaml contains a Ressource dictionary that merges different styles together in a single dictionary.

In my .NET MAUI App.xaml I tried adding the dictionary like this:

```xml
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyPackage.UI;component/Styles/MyStyle.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

When I try building the project I get the error:

> Invalid URI: Invalid port specified.

Am I doing something wrong? I thought `pack://application:,,,` should give me the correct port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to include a style from a NuGet package inside the .NET Maui App.xaml?

About how to use a style from NuGet, you can refer to this case: [.NET MAUI - Styles packed in a MAUI Library are not available for InteliSense after released as nuget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73630174/net-maui-styles-packed-in-a-maui-library-are-not-available-for-intelisense-af). The question section described usage for NuGet.

In addition, you can see the official doc: [Merge resource dictionaries from other assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/resource-dictionaries?view=net-maui-7.0#merge-resource-dictionaries-from-other-assemblies).

Hope these can help you.

Comment: Hey Jianwei Sun, actually your links were very helpful. Thank you! :-) 

For anyone stumbling upon this question, here are some things I had to consider for the solution: 

The nuget I was using did contain a regular class library and the style that was contained was a regular WPF resource dictionary. Although they might look very similar, they are NOT reusable in .NET Maui. I had to go ahead and create a .NET Maui class library, and create new resource dictionaries with the styles I needed. 

Those dictionaires need to have: x:Class attribute, code behind + Maui Xaml build action set.